# Create own workflow with sending email based on item

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

I need to create my own workflow, based on a yes/no item.

If the item is yes then it sends an email for approval to one person, but if it is no it send an email for approval to another person.

I have tried creating a workflow in SharePoint Designer but it is very confusing. 
Any tips or help for me?

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial will really help you

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125120/Step-by-Step-Guide-in-Developing-your-own-Workflow

All The Best.